# How would I combine these tables

Tags: postgresql

Ive been prompted with the task of writing code in PostgreSQL on coderpad.io to combine information from 3 tables into 1.

If you go to https://coderpad.io/sandbox and switch the syntax to postgresql, and enter the following,

```
SELECT * FROM employees;
SELECT * FROM projects;
SELECT * FROM employees_projects;
```

You will see the info related to the employees we need.

We are trying to make a table that combines the three employees who are working on "Building a cool site" into one.

I've just been writing this on coderpad.io/sandbox and switching the syntax to PostgreSQL

```
SELECT  d.name, e.first_name, p.title
FROM employees_projects ep, projects p, employees e
  JOIN departments d
    ON d.id = e.id
WHERE ep.project_id IN ('2')
  AND e.department_id IN ('2')
  AND p.id IN ('1')
;
```

I was also told that there should not be any numbers in the above lines (WHERE/AND)

```
SELECT d.name, e.first_name, p.title
FROM employees e, projects p, departments d, employees_projects ep
WHERE ep.employee_id = d.id
  AND p.id = '1'
  AND d.id = '2'
  AND e.department_id = '2';
```

This is the desired query result:

```
Department Name | Employee Name |   Project Title
----------------+---------------+-------------------
Engineering     | Cailin        | Build a cool site
Engineering     | Mike          | Build a cool site
Engineering     | Ian           | Build a cool site
```

Apparently, though the answer is correct, how I obtained it was not. 
I feel like i'm missing something really obvious, but cant see it.

Comment: tip: your first query contains the proper solution for linking `department` and `employees`

Answer (score 0):

It occurs to me that you 'unsatisfied with your results because although you are querying for a specific project (Building a cool site) that actually does not appear in your query but instead you hard code the id's needed. Not a very satisfying method, I would agree.

What you are missing is following the chain of id's from what your target (project.title) back to the necessary information in the other tables. I've had to make a couple assumptions but the following should point you in the right direction. Note - I've updated the structure to the more modern JOIN syntax):

```
select d.name
     , e.first_name
     , p.title
  from projects p 
       join employees_projects ep on (ep.project_id = p.id)
            join employees e on (ep.employee.id = e.id)
                 join departments d on (e.department_id = d.id)
 where p.title = 'Building a cool site';
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and information, I appreciate it greatly.

Ill start working with what you have provided.